# Set font bold to particular column of a Flex Grid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am using flex grid to display set of records. How can i set

**font bold to a particular column of the flex grid**?

If anybody knows this pls help me... thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

This will make the second column bold:

```
$("#table1").find("tr td:nth-child(2)").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Works for any table.